# How to select all elements that are not in an element with a particular id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select for example all divs that are not contained by an element that has id `myId`?

The `not()` selector might have the functionality to accomplish this but I do not know how.

So for example:

```
<div>
   <div id="myId">
      <input/>
      <input/>
      <input/>
   </div>
   <input>I only want to select this one</input>
</div>
```

Comment: `div > input:not(#myId > input)`. Or if you can put a class/id on the outer div, just `#outerDiv > input` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to filter out the inputs you don't want:

```js
$('input').not('#myId input').css({ // if inputs are always direct child, you can use #myId>input
  'border-color': 'red'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="myId">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly confusing because you say you want to select `div`s but then your example indicates you want to select an `input`. Assuming it's the `input` you want,

```
$(input:not(#myID > input))
```

should do it.